# In android: how to call the another fragment with in tab bar Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

In tab bar activity using fragments.i have tree tabs and i need to load the following class Fragment in same tab.

```
public class FindFragmentActivity extends Fragment {

      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.findpartner_list_activity,container, false);
        return rootView;
        }
}
```

I have tried following code to calling fragment:

```
FindFragmentActivity fragment = new FindFragmentActivity();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.activity_mypartner_view,fragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Logcat:

```
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030003 (com.tech.cf:layout/findpartner_list_activity) for fragment FindFragmentActivity{417a2390 #1 id=0x7f030003}
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-08 18:52:17.755: E/AndroidRuntime(4021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

its crash the app.how can i call and load within tab bar content.

**Edit:**

```
code:
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.layout_partnerlistview, new FindFragmentActivity())
    .commit();

Layout:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_partnerlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            .
            .
            .
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Its also cause  the same error (No view found).

Comment: golden rule of help: if you have a crash, always post logcat

Answer (score 2):

`Fragments` cannot be called as `Activities`, they can be only initialized via `FragmentManager`, so this piece of code make no sense:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),FindFragmentActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

`Activity` is hosting `Fragments`, so your intent should include explicit\implicit reference to corresponding `Activity` and inside it's `onCreate` you can invoke the needed fragment. Also `FragmentTransaction's` methods can be chained:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.<my container>, new FindFragmentActivity())
    .commit();
```

**EDIT**

The first try is correct (with using `FragmentManager`), but with a small mistake. For a first parameter of `replace` method you should provide not the id of layout, but the id of the view (R.id.myView) in *existing* layout of Activity, that will host your fragments. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) for example

Comment: Your ans also crash the app.logcat is above question.

Comment: @chimbu is this the layout for the Activity, where `FindFragmentActivity` is hosted? Have you called setContentView(<this layout>) at the `onCreate`?

Comment: this is not activity its is Fragment.